# Stub a class private method with Sinon and Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I would like to [stub](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v12.0.1/stubs/) with [sinon](https://sinonjs.org/) a [private class method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_methods) in a backend Node.js app. Here's a sample class:

```js
class MyDbase {
  constructor() {...}

  #connect() {...}

  isConnected() {...}
}
```

I'm going to [stub](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v12.0.1/stubs/) it with the following piece of code:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const MyDbase = require('./class');

describe(`MyDbase class tests`, () => {
  it(`connect method`, () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub(MyDbase.prototype, '#connect').returns(0);
    const myDbase = new MyDbase();
    ...
    stub.restore();
  });

  it(`isConnected method`, () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub(MyDbase.prototype, 'isConnected').returns(0);
    const myDbase = new MyDbase();
    ...
    stub.restore();
  });
});
```

When I run the tests with [mocha](https://mochajs.org/), the first one raises the following error:

```sh
TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent property #connect
```

Obviously if I stub the `isConnected` public class method everything works as expected.
Is it possible to stub [private class methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_methods) with [sinon](https://sinonjs.org/)?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Tried, hit the same wall, and then decided to stub the external library used inside private method.

Comment: Running into the same issue. Did you ever find a solution? I'm thinking, due to the nature of private properties/methods, this will likely be something sinon is simply unable to do.

Comment: Sadly the short answer is no @jeremysawesome. You can hack it a little bit by calling a testable helper function from within the private method for example. Not applicable to all scenarios.